# How to display an info page (not installed on system)?

Tags: emacs, texinfo

I'm working on documentation for a large eLisp library. I have it in *.info file. I would like to be able to display its contents (also during development) in Emacs somehow, but I can't find a way to display it in info mode (I can only open it as source).

Ideally, I'd also be interested in a mechanism to add this file to the contents of `info-finder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a shortcut, you can launch a file from within a dired buffer directly into info mode by pressing the 'I' key on the file.

Just ensure you've loaded the dired-x package (included in 24) and have the variable dired-bind-info set to true

```
(load "dired-x")
(setq dired-x-hands-off-my-keys nil)
(setq dired-bind-info t)
(dired-x-bind-find-file)
```

- Chris

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> will prompt you for an info file to read.

As for installing a new info file, you basically add the file to a directory in your `INFOPATH` and then add an entry for it in the Info Directory node (i.e. the `dir` file).

You can get into some of the details here:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(info) Expert Info` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Or ask Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=install+info+file

Comment: Ah, my mistake; I saw the "(not installed on system)" and then proceeded to completely mis-read the bit about "info-finder" as you wanting to install the info file.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for `info` says:

```
info is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `info.el'.
It is bound to C-h i, <help> i.
[....]
In interactive use, a non-numeric prefix argument directs
this command to read a file name from the minibuffer.
```

So: <kbd>C-u C-h i</kbd>.

(`info-finder` looks for keywords in source code, not in info files, so it doesn't make sense to add an info file to it.)